# Loading Word add-ins on Windows Server

Tags: office-js, windows-server-2016

I am trying to load a Word add-in in the following context:

- Windows Server 2016
- Word Click-to-Run version 1804

But it cannot load. I've tried with a couple of other add-ins (Scrip Lab, too) and I've tried the online version of Word, too, on IE11 (also on Windows Server 2016), but none work.

My guess is that add-ins are not supported on Windows Server, but I didn't find such restrictions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins so I'm not a 100% sure.

Is there any way to make add-ins work in this context?

Answer (score 2):

ESC (Enhanced Security Configuration) in Internet Explorer is turned on by default in Windows Server. It has to be off for Office Add-ins.

Comment: I have turned it off and put all IE security options to the minimum (except for Restricted sites because add-ins won't load with no security policy for Restricted sites), but I still cannot load add-ins. Is there something else I can try?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cannot load"? Do you get an error message? What are the steps that lead to the error?

Comment: did you checked that in trust center (within Word and inside the trusted Add-in Catalogs tab) the first two options are NOT checked?

Comment: @JuanBalmori the first two options are not checked, I can confirm.

Comment: @RickKirkham By cannot load I mean the initial loading screen is always there and the add in seems to be infinitely loading (ScriptLab).

Comment: I have also tried loading an add-in directly through a manifest file (I've created a shared folder and added it to trusted catalogue which I usually use for testing on Windows Word) and the result is the same.

Comment: Also - I have tried logging into the server as a non-admin account and then I get the message, when I attempt to open the Store: "Content within this application coming from the website listed below is being blocked by IE Enhanced Security Configuration" and the website is store.office.com. However, when I check the server config, it says that IE Enhanced Security Config. is OFF (both when I view the config as an admin or a regular user). At least this is some pointer so I can search how to definitely turn it off.

Comment: One more update: the whole service is hosted on Amazon AppStream 2.0 so it might be that there's an extra security layer on top of the Win. Server blocking the add ins, in which case this would not be a MS issue.

Comment: I searched in Bing and found that other people have seen the phenomenon of turning off ESC in Server Manager but it doesn't get turned off. I recommend you research that and see how others have fixed it.